# Convergent or Divergent using Limits

Tags: calculus, limits

Using limits evaluate the following improper integral or show it is divergent
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty x^3e^{-x^4}dx$$
I did $$\lim_{c\to-\infty}\int_{c}^0 x^3e^{-x^4}dx+\lim_{b\to\infty}\int_{0}^b x^3e^{-x^4}dx$$after this do I use integration by parts or is there another simpler method out there, cause integration by parts seems like a mission, one which I don't feel like embarking on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the substitution $u=x^4$ to calculate $$\int x^3e^{-x^4}dx$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Notice the fact that the integrand is [symmetrical](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Even_and_odd_functions) with respect to the origin.